# How to prevent a directive from binding to elements within a controllers scope in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular app, MyApp, that depends on external modules (two different map solutions), and I need them both but in different controllers (different modules within MyApp even).

The problem is the two modules both have directives that bind to the same argument ('center' in this case), which causes them both do manipulate a single element. What I want is for one directive to be active inside one controller and the other directive to be active inside another controller - so not have them inpact my elements at the same time.

I don't want to change the code of the external modules to achive this.

Comment: I assume you are not using isolated scopes in your directives then?

Comment: I'm not in control of the directives, they're part of the modules i depend on. And would isolated scopes or not really make any difference? I simply don't want both directives to have an inpact on my elements in a given controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a very interesting question.  The answer below is incomplete, and, frankly, a bit hackish, but it demonstrates a way to rename a directive in another module without modifying the source of the module itself.  There is a lot of work to do to make this anywhere near production ready and it absolutely can be improved.

The caveats to the solution are that once a directive is renamed, the "old" name will no longer work.  It also depends on some angular conventions that might be changed with future versions, etc, so it's not future proof.  It also might fail for complex directives, and I haven't really done any testing on it.

However, it demonstrates that it can be done, and the concept might lead to a feature angular needs (the ability to namespace external modules in order to prevent conflicts such as the one your are experiencing).

I think that if your use case is fairly simple, this will solve your problem, but I wouldn't recommend using it in the general case yet.

```
(function () {
          var util = angular.module('util', [], function ($compileProvider) {
            util.$compileProvider = $compileProvider
          })
          .factory('$directiveRename', function () {
              var noop = function () { return function () { }; };
              return function (module, directive, newDirective) {
                  var injector = angular.injector(['ng', module]);

                  var directive = injector.get(directive + 'Directive');
                  if(directive)
                  {

                      //there can be multiple directives with the same name but different priority, etc.  This is an area where this could definitely be improved.  Will only work with simple directives.
                      var renamedDirective = angular.copy(directive[0]);
                      delete renamedDirective['name'];

                      util.$compileProvider.directive(newDirective, function () {
                          return renamedDirective;
                      });
                   }

                  //noop the old directive
                  //http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/16734506/remove-a-directive-from-module-in-angular
                  angular.module(module).factory(directive + 'Directive', noop);
              };
          });
      })();
```

Example usage:

```
angular.module('app', ['module1', 'module2', 'util'])
  .run(function ($directiveRename) {

      $directiveRename('module1', 'test', 'testa');
      $directiveRename('module2', 'test', 'testb');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, slightly less hackish answer.

Add the following immediately after the script tag that includes angular (before any other modules are loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var angularModule = angular.bind(angular, angular.module);

        angular.module = function (moduleName, requires, configFn) {
            var instance = angularModule(moduleName, requires, configFn);

            var directive = instance.directive;

            instance.directive = function (directiveName, directiveFactory) {

                //You can rename your directive here based on the module and directive name.  I don't know the module and directive names for your particular problem.  This obviously could be generalized.
                if (instance.name == 'module1' && directiveName == 'test') {
                    directiveName = 'testa';
                }

                if (instance.name == 'module2' && directiveName == 'test') {
                    directiveName = 'testb';
                }

                return directive(directiveName, directiveFactory);
            }

            return instance;
        };
</script>
```

This works by intercepting calls to module.directive and allowing you the opportunity to rename the directive before it is created.